# After I get the user profile from RPX how do I set the user as authenticated?

Tags: asp.net, openid, rpxnow, rpx

I am using RPX for authentication. Now I get the user profile with identifier. What to do next to set authentication cookie and other things? Also the logout feature. in ASP.net 3.5 and C#.

Answer (score 0):

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` works. :)  Then you can use a database to store those "other things".

Logout with `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how to do so in ASP. But I have done same thing using PHP. First thing you can do is, you can map the RPX account with your local site accounts. Just save profile information you get from RPX and create a new account in your site using that information. You will have to save that profile data in your database's table that you use for login and register.

After user logs in to your site using RPX, store the profile information given by RPX in session. Now you are done with your requirement. Now you can treat that user as a normal user of your site.